# Netlogo: Code is asking patches to move, but the instructions are on ask turtle

Tags: netlogo, patch

So, I ve previously asked about the patches not storing a certain neighbour value, thanks to Matteo, JenB and Lena i was able to progress further. Sicen then the code has advanced a bit and thus I have encountered a new error.

First, the code works if copy and pasted but two things are necessary, i dont have negatives so it woud be necessary to change the center to the corner and i dont know how to not create the setup button so it would be needed.

Now, the code generates 3 zones with 3 colors, and each border moves according to a random number. With this, the turtle that is close to the border should change both the color of the patch and its own color, whilst turning randomly and moving.

The issue is that i dont know what im missing but the patch does change color, but the turtle doesnt change or move, saying that the instructions are being aplied by patches and patches dont move, which makes sense. But why? im setting the conditions that if the turtles have certain energy then they should do the thing im asking.

The problem is, again, in to move-potrero with the parts that are in semicolon.

```
turtles-own [energia]
 patches-own
[bordear
abandono
reforestado
potrerizado
temperatura
humedad
dosel
]
breed [ potreros potrero ]  
breed [ bordes borde ] 
breed [ bosques bosque ]

to setup
  clear-all

  ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 30 and
    pxcor >= min-pxcor and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 35
    set temperatura 26.5
    set dosel 1
   set humedad 90.4
  ]
 ;Potrero
  ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 60 and
    pxcor >= 30 and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 44
    set temperatura 29
    set dosel 84.3
   set humedad 79.3;
  ]
  ;Borde
  ask patches with [
    pxcor <= 90 and
    pxcor >= 60 and
    pycor <= 60 and
    pycor >= min-pycor ] [
    set pcolor 66
   set temperatura 26.3
   set dosel 85.2
   set humedad 94 ;
  ]
  ;Bosque

 ;se establece la forma de la rana
 
 ; Se establecen las condiciones de las ranas, tamaño color y lugar de aparicion. La energia sera igual en todas las ranas en el set up.

   create-potreros 50

  [ set size 3        ;; easier to see
    set color yellow
setxy random xcor random ycor
move-to one-of patches with [pcolor = 35]
    set heading random 45 + 45
    set energia 50
 ]   ;; red = not carrying food

 ;Potrero


 
    reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask potreros [
    if energia < 50 [descansar-potrero]
    if energia >= 50 and energia <= 80 [move-potrero]
    if energia > 80 [ if ticks mod 50 = 0 [reproducirse]]
    set heading random 270
      fd 1
 set energia energia - 2
  morir]

  ask patches [ reforestacion ]
  ask patches [ deforestacion ]
  ask patches [abandonacion]
  ask patches [borderizacion]


if ticks >= 500 [stop]
tick
end

to reforestacion
  if pcolor = 44 [
     set reforestado count neighbors with [pcolor = 66] ]
  if reforestado >= 3 [if random 100 <= 50 [
    set pcolor 66
    set temperatura 27 + random 3
    set humedad 90 + random 5
    set dosel 70 + random 10 ]
  ]


end


to deforestacion
  if pcolor = 44 [
     set potrerizado count neighbors with [pcolor = 35] ]
  if potrerizado >= 3 [if random 100 <= 50 [
    set pcolor 35
    set temperatura 26.5 + random 3
    set humedad 80 + random 10
    set dosel 40 + random 10]
  ]


end

to abandonacion
  if pcolor = 35 [
     set abandono count neighbors with [pcolor = 44] ]
  if abandono >= 3 [if random 100 <= 50 [
    set pcolor 44
    set temperatura 26.5 + random 3
    set humedad 80 + random 10
    set dosel 40 + random 10]
  ]

end

to borderizacion
  if pcolor = 66 [
     set bordear count neighbors with [pcolor = 44] ]
  if bordear >= 3 [if random 100 <= 50 [
    set pcolor 44
    set temperatura 27 + random 3
    set humedad 90 + random 5
    set dosel 70 + random 10]
  ]
end

to move-potrero
  ask neighbors in-radius 2
     [if temperatura >= 28.6 or temperatura <= 22.6 or dosel >= 5 or humedad <= 84
      [ set pcolor red
       ;facexy random 30 random 60
      ;fd 5
      ;set energia energia - 10]]
    ;[ask potreros [descansar-potrero]]
  ]]



end

to descansar-potrero
  ifelse pcolor = 35 [
    set energia energia + 6]
  [set energia energia + 1]

end

to reproducirse
  if energia > 80 [ if random 100 > 60 [set energia energia - 70
      hatch 1 [ rt random-float 360 fd 2
      set energia energia / 3]]]
end
  to morir
  if energia <= 1 [die]

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### 1

The thing is that you are asking patches to perform turtle commands (such as `facexy` and `fd`) because `neighbors` reports patches. From the [NetLogo dictionary](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#neighbors):

> Reports an agentset containing the 8 surrounding patches (neighbors) or 4 surrounding patches (neighbors4).

Therefore, the trick will be to substitute `neighbors` with `turtles`;

```
to move-potrero
  ask turtles in-radius 2 [
   if temperatura >= 28.6 or temperatura <= 22.6 or dosel >= 5 or humedad <= 84 [
     set pcolor red
     facexy random 30 random 30
     fd 5
     set energia energia - 10
    ] 
  ]
  
  ask potreros [descansar-potrero]
end
```

The thing that allows this code to run is that turtles can operate on the variables of the patch they're standing on (see [User Manual](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/) > Programming Guide > Variables).
So, for example, asking turtles to check `temperatura` will not generate an error, even if `temperatura` is `patches-own`.

Another option could have been to ask patches (i.e. the ones you invoked with `neighbors`) to ask "their" turtles to do things. You can do this by using `turtles-here`:

```
to move-potrero
  ask neighbors in-radius 2 [
   if temperatura >= 28.6 or temperatura <= 22.6 or dosel >= 5 or humedad <= 84 [
     ask turtles-here [
       set pcolor red
       facexy random 30 random 30
       fd 5
       set energia energia - 10
      ] 
    ]
  ]
  
  ask potreros [descansar-potrero]
end
```

With this setup, each neighboring patch checks those patch-related conditions and, if one of them is true, asks every turtle there to do something.
The result **would be** identical, although I imagine the former option requires less computation time: up to you to choose the style you prefer.

Why did I say "**would be** identical"? See next point.

### 2

The expression `neighbors in-radius 2` doesn't make a lot of sense in NetLogo: `neighbors` will report the 8 neighboring patches, and these will not change with a certain radius. I could also write `neighbors in-radius 1000`, but I will always receive the same 8 patches because only those 8 are neighbors to a certain patch.

This is particularly important to know because NetLogo won't tell you, i.e. it won't give an error message if you write `neighbors in-radius 2` (in fact that is not a syntactical mistake, because `in-radius` comes after an agentset and before a number, just as it [requires](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#in-radius)): NetLogo will simply continue by reporting only the neighboring patches.

For this reason, the option you should prefer from Point 1 above is the first option, i.e. the one with `ask turtles in-radius 2`. In fact, that is the only option that will let you play with `in-radius`.

### 3

Note that a `resize-world` command exists (see [here](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#resize-world)). By including 0 as `min-pxcor` and as `min-pycor`, you will be able to automate in your code the fact that your world does not include negative coordinates.

Comment: Matteo Thank you so much. First didnt know that i was unable to modify neighbours so great correction! With that, your correction of the turtles is extremely useful, and i thought that the correct answer would be something like your second suggestion, i didnt considered asking the turtles themselves. I Really appreciate you taking the time. Hope this is the last one, at least for this project.